# Apache web server localhost works but IP gives error code 404

Tags: apache-2.2

When I use localhost the index page is displayed. When I use the IP outside of my network or within my network I get a not found 404 error. Please suggest possible issues or fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a multi-site server or a singel-site server?  If, for example, you're using ISPConfig or a similar tool + maybe Apache you will most likely have the default Apache http root reply on your IP/localhost and then have your site root reply on the other.

I would actually expect your to get a reply for your IP and not localhost on a multi-site server to be more likely, but it could be the other way around.  Just my thought about this...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NAT? If so, most routers require you to use the LAN IP inside your network and don't route the traffic correctly if you use the WAN IP + port forwarding, since the traffic comes from inside the NAT. From the outside you have to use the WAN IP and confirm that your ports are forwarded correctly.